# PHP accented characters in POST submit

Tags: php, forms, post, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a HTML form on submit.php, the page is encoded as UTF-8 (using a meta tag), when the form is submitted to process.php (via POST), some of the variables are stored in the session, and the page uses Header: Location to go back to submit.php, which then uses the session variables to redisplay some of the entered information.

If I enter an accented character, for example é (&eacute), when the page returns to submit.php, it does not render the character correctly, I get an ã (&atilde) and an © (&copy) instead.

Where should I be looking to solve this problem? I'm assuming it's server side, as the rendered page is always UTF-8 (the browser confirms the page is UTF-8 before and after submitting)

**Solution:**

The string was being passed through htmlentities() at one point, which it turns out has a default character encoding of ISO-8859-1 The answer was to simply specify 'UTF-8' in the function call.

Comment: Of what characters consists you "utf-8 encoded page"? Regular latin characters?

Comment: Define "does not render correctly". What happens?

Comment: By "not render correctly" I mean I get an "&atilde" and an "&copy", instead of the "&eacute" I was expecting.

Comment: @beeglebug are you 100% certain the page gets rendered as UTF-8? Can you check in your browser settings? What session handler are you using, the default one?

Comment: In fact, there shouldn't be html-entities at all, no "&copy" nor "&eacute". Check your script that alters data. The code you wrote. It's the reason of the problem.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: They aren't html-entities, they are the actual characters, I was simply writing it like that for the purposes of the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Pekka: The browser confirms UTF-8 both pre and post submit, and I am using the default session handler.

Comment: Have you checked if your file is in UTF8 ? Some editors put the file in ISO by default, even if you set headers and the html meta. In Zend Studio for example you need to go to the properties of the file to change this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`é` being turned into `~©` is a sure-fire sign that the 2-byte UTF-8 character at some point gets interpreted in a 1-byte character set (most likely ISO-8859-1).

You need to find where this happens, and fix it.

Maybe show some code - maybe somebody has an idea.

Comment: Unfortunately the code is rather convoluted, but essentially it does $_SESSION['thestring'] = $_POST['thestring'] on process.php, and then echo $_SESSION['thestring'] on submit.php.

It's not anything to do with using header() and sessions is it? Does PHP have an internal character encoding that I need to set in order for the 2 byte character is always interpreted as 2-byte as it is passed around?

Comment: Thanks Pekka, it was exactly what you said, something was using ISO-8859-1.

Comment: It is also important to define the charset early in the file (first 1024 chars), or it may get ignored.

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SESSION['thestring'] = $_POST['thestring']
```

Cannot reasonably be the problem source. Here PHP is just copying the two bytes *verbatim*. No charset conversion is going to occour here. Hence any conversion likely happened before or thereafter.

To make sure $_POST isn't the cultprit, check that your `<form>` contains the `accept-charset="UTF-8"`. That's often overlooked. Second, for testing purposes output the `$_POST["thestring"]` right on receival. If the problem arises here, you'll need Firebug and xdebug..

It's very unlikely that the session store or PHP modify the string contents in `$_SESSION`. That's why I would presume the bug to be in the output page after all. Make a separate test page, and `print $_SESSION["thestring"]` there. Don't overlook the `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");` for it.